# What's the meaning of `struct decay<T, R(A..., ...)>`

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename ...A>
struct decay<T, R(A..., ...)> { using type = R(*)(A..., ...); };
```

What's the exact meaning of that? I need some help~

Comment: Where did you see that code?  It looks similar to what someone would reasonably use for implementing `std::decay`, but there is no reason for the `T`...  My first assumption is that you copied it wrong.

Comment: @Yakk: This code is from boost::hana.

Comment: Aha: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1detail_1_1decay.html it is an optimization.  Which explains the otherwise nonsensical design; they are working around template instantiation inefficiencies.

Comment: So my next question: this is within a details namespace of a metaprogramming library.  So it isn't really intended to be easy to understand.  What about it is confusing you?  Do you know what templates are?  Template specialization?  Traits classes?  Do you know what `std::decay` is?  Do you understand the concept of function argument type decay?  "What's the exact meaning of this" is not a useful question.  Be more specific.

Comment: @Yakk: Sorry for that. I want to know what the code above is different from `struct decay<T, R(A...)>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int foo(int);
int bar(int, ...);
```

these are two different functions.  `foo` is of type `int(int)`.  `bar` is of type `int(int,...)`.

`...` is C-style varargs, not to be confused with variardic template arguments which also uses `...`.

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename ...A>
struct decay<T, R(A..., ...)> { using type = R(*)(A..., ...); };
```

This part of an implementation of an optimized version of `std::decay` within `boost::hana`.  The `typename T` and `T` parts are red herrings, part of that optimization.

It is a specialization that matches `R(A..., ...)`, where `A...` and `R` are deduced from a function signature.

If you passed `double(int, char, ...)` as the 2nd argument to this `hana::details::decay`, `R` would be `double` and `A...` would be `int, char`.  And the `...` would "match the C-style varags".

This particular specialization's purpose to to map function signatures that end in C-style varargs to pointers to the same signature.  So it maps `double(int, char, ...)` to `double(*)(int, char, ...)`.

C style varargs are not the same as template variardic arguments.  They predate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I want to know.

Answer (score 6):

This specialization is one of the specializations that enact the decay of a function type to the corresponding pointer-to-function type, which mirrors the way function lvalues decay to function pointer prvalues.

This particular specialization is used for variable-argument functions (those whose parameter list ends in an ellipsis so that it accepts arguments that don't match any parameters).

Comment: I don't understand why there would be a two-argument `decay` for that purpose.

Comment: `template <typename R, typename ...A>struct decay<R(A..., ...)> { using type = R(*)(A..., ...); };` is a specialization of `decay` that catches function signatures of a specific type.  I don't understand why you'd have a two-argument version of decay, then ignore the first argument.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I cannot quite understand what you have said, could you  please explain more?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1detail_1_1decay.html -- this is from a details namespace, and it is a optimization hack.  That explains why it makes little sense as code.

Comment: @JohnSmith That specialization is for functions with variable number of arguments, like `int printf(const char *, ...)`. In this piece: `R(A..., ...);`, the first ellipsis expands the parameter pack A, and the second ellipsis remains as a part of the function type.

Comment: @KerrekSB This `decay` has **two parameters**.  Not one.  This is why it is confusing.  It turns out it is an optimization from within `hana::details`.  I presume it leaves the `T` around to generate marginally better error messages and they found this (somehow) did not lead to compilation overhead.  I am surprised that the first argument doesn't lead to extra compilation costs, but I am no expert at template micro optimization.

Comment: @Yakk: Ah, yes, how did I miss that :-S

Comment: @JohnSmith: Could you be specific about which particular detail you don't understand and would like explained?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Sorry for that. I want to know what the code above is different from `template <typename T, typename R, typename ...A>
struct decay<T, R(A...)> { using type = R(*)(A...); };`

Comment: @JohnSmith: Same difference as `void f(int)` and `void f(int, ...)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thanks a lot.